# Al poner el foco en la página, pasar el cursor por encima, todo el texto se me cambia a itálica sin estar programado así

Tags: html, css

Cuando pongo el foco en la página index.html (sólo me pasa en esa), es decir, al pasar por encima el cursor, todo el texto se transforma en cursiva, en itálica, sin yo haber programado nada para que eso ocurra.
Es esta la url: https://www.amadoresdecristo.org/index.html
Soy incapaz de encontrar el fallo o saber por qué pasa eso.
Incluyo el código de la página y el css.

Comment: Las preguntas en [es.so] han de ser **auto contenidas**, eso significa que todo el código relevante a la misma debe estar contenido en la pregunta y no en un enlace externo ni en imagenes. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver la regla css que se aplica es:

**estilo.css 95-99**

```
    a:hover { 
    color : red; 
    font-style : italic; 
    text-decoration : none; 
    }
```

Dicho esto mis conocimientos de web no son muy avanzados pero sospecho que tiene que ver con que en la **linea 11 del html** declares la etiqueta

```
<a name="arriba">
```

y dentro de esta incluyas todo el contenido de la página. En vistas de que esta etiqueta no contiene ningun enlace (href) te recomendaria o eliminarla o cambiar el tipo de etiqueta a un div o alguna con la función que le corresponde.
Probando en el navegador al eliminar esta etiqueta se resuelve el problema sin modificar el css.

Un saludo, espero que ayude.

Comment: "En vistas de que esta etiqueta no contiene ningun enlace (href) te recomendaria o eliminarla o cambiar el tipo de etiqueta a un div o alguna con la función que le corresponde"

Si cambia la etiqueta por otra le dejará de funcionar el botón "ir arriba" que tiene al final. Debería cambiarla siguiendo una buena estructura, quizás sacando el Html fuera y usando un boton

Comment: Inicio felicitandote por responder. Sin embargo esta pregunta tiene el gran problema que en 5 o 10 minutos la página enlazada desaparece o cambia y tu respuesta se queda en el aire y ya no se entiende ni es útil a otros. Por eso se suele pedir que preguntas (y respuestas) tengan lo esencial como parte de ellas y no en recursos externos. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y [ask].

Answer (score 0):

esa web tiene varios errores graves y está muy obsoleta. El primer fallo que tiene es que toda la web (o la vista) esta dentro de un `<a>` para ir arriba (lo que hace que falle), luego toda la web está hecha con tablas, eso ya con HTML5 no es una buena práctica por lo que te diría de migrar la estructura de la web poco a poco.

El problema viene dado por ese `<a>` que engloba la web que tiene un estilo al hacer hover

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Aún así recomiendo que mires como pasar la web a HTML5 para hacerla más mantenible y intentar usar una buena praxis para evitar estos errores

Comment: Inicio felicitandote por responder. Sin embargo esta pregunta tiene el gran problema que en 5 o 10 minutos la página enlazada desaparece o cambia y tu respuesta se queda en el aire y ya no se entiende ni es útil a otros. Por eso se suele pedir que preguntas (y respuestas) tengan lo esencial como parte de ellas y no en recursos externos. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y [ask].

Comment: jachguate totalmente de acuerdo contigo, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Gracias